# Why type deduction fails for a class member?

Tags: c++, c++17

Let's assume that we have this small code:

```
template<typename T>
struct Test {
    Test(T t) : m_t(t) {}
    T m_t;
};

int main() {
    Test t = 1;
}
```

This code easily compiles with `[T=int]` for `Test` class. Now if I write a code like this:

```
template<typename T>
struct Test {
    Test(T t) : m_t(t) {}
    T m_t;
};

struct S {
    Test t = 1;
};

int main() {
    S s;
}
```

This code fails to compile with the following error:

```
invalid use of template-name 'Test' without an argument list
```

I need to write it like `Test<int> t = 1;` as a class member to work. Any idea why this happens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a difference between your two snippets - first `Test t = 1` declares, defines, and initializes a new variable while the second only declares a member variable and specifies how it **might** be initialized.

The default member initializer is relevant only in the context of a constructor without `t` in its member initializer list and there can easily be multiple constructors, each initializing `t` in different way.

The following is valid C++, what should type of `t` be deduced to?

```
struct S {
    Test t = 1;
    S(){}
    S(int):t(1){}
    S(double):t(true){}
};
```

If this were to be supported, you hit the implementation issue of making type/size/layout of the class dependent on the definition of constructors which are likely in different translation units. Therefore it would make it impossible to define include classes such as `S` (if one moved the definitions to some .cpp) via header files.

Answer (score 8):

The reason

```
struct S {
    Test t = 1;
};
```

does not work is because you aren't actually doing `Test t = 1;`.  An in class initializer is just a convenient way to tell the compiler what value to initialize `t` with when one is not provided.  What "actually" gets generated is

```
struct S {
    S() : t(1) {} // created by the compiler
    Test t;
};
```

and here you can more easily see that `t` isn't specified with an initializer until you call the constructor.

Comment: If I may nitpick, `Test t=1;` is copy initialization, while `:t(1) {}` is direct initialization but the point should be clear.

Comment: This is where syntactic sugar causes code cavities.